# Facebook app with multiple country code top level domains (ccTLD)

Tags: c#, asp.net, facebook

Let's assume we have a web application that is served through the following domains:
www.something.com
www.something.co.uk
www.something.de

I wonder if there is a way to authenticate user's facebook account, to get access to their wall from these different domains and use the same facebook application.

I don't know if I can make that change via facebook application's settings page or via source code.

(I am using facebook developer toolkit for .NET in asp.net environment)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From my understanding this is easy to do as long as the application that first logs the user in gets all the appropriate permissions to do this the action you want to do.

then all your other domains need to do is use the same app key etc to make its requests to view a users walls and it should happen regardless of the user session even being active.

once a user approves your application to get info to "about me" and "wall" etc the application can do this while the user still has your application id approved on their account.

your application would work this this:

- you have a single application with a single URL and single application id and secret
- the user logs into you application and you request permission to view their wall etc.
- you then redirect to your appropriate domain name - but make sure you keep the entire querystring that facebook sent your application (including the session querystring element)
- continue to carry around the querystring if you move between pages

Comment: so are you suggesting that facebook developer just needs one facebook application or multiple (one per domain name) ?

Comment: Only a single - the one for which all requests originally come through

Answer (score 1):

Facebook now supports multiple domains for this exact purpose as detailed on their [latest blog post](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/570/).  Just plug www.something.com, www.something.co.uk, www.something.de all into the domain box on the app settings page.