# If my website uses Facebook to login, do I need a separate Facebook Application for each domain name?

Tags: facebook, authentication

I'm using Facebook to login people into my website. Now, does this mean I will need a separate Facebook application for each domain name? And if I also have a dev and test server .. i need separate applications for them also?! (EEKS!)

eg.

domains:

- localhost.www.mysite.com
- dev.www.mysite.com
- www.mysite.com
- www.mysite.com.au
- www.mysite.co.uk

.. etc..

cheers :)

EDIT:

[Someone tried asking the same thing](http://forum.developers.facebook.net/viewtopic.php?id=82914) in the Facebook forums .. but got no answer :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Facebook just added support for multiple domains according to their [latest blog post](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/570/).

Answer (score 1):

When you are coding Facebook application, or implementing Facebook API in your application, Facebook identifies your application only by your App ID, and your APP secret.

So if you use the same App ID and App Secret I think that Facebook will not have problem with your different domains.

Comment: Sure about that? I'm getting authentication errors when i'm trying to log in any user ... because (all but one Facebook) SiteId's are different to the url i'm testing under.

Comment: Well I haven't try this yet, but if you are using this application only for facebook login then Facebook is not the problem, your problem will be reading the cookie which is set for the domain you are logging from another domain.
If you can do this please do tell how :)
In other hand I found post on facebook forum where some administrator is suggesting to use multiple applications for multiple domains.
http://forum.developers.facebook.net/viewtopic.php?pid=320160

Comment: I don't understand what the cookie problem is? If an existing user connects to my site from domain #2, then need to log in again. simple. But maybe check out cross-domain-cookies (eg. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/554436/cross-domain-cookies-with-formsauthentication)

Comment: Yes I've found that solution but I don't like it, because it has few redirection, but it seems it's the only one.

I've found this answer which is the same see if it helps:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3369823/facebook-app-with-multiple-country-code-top-level-domains-cctld

Answer (score 0):

No you can use same with all domains but it is recommended that u use different for localhost as u need to test

Comment: Ok -- so how do i have the same application for my live/production domains?

Comment: u need to put it on single module like single turn n use it, make service for authebtication

Comment: thanks for the comment .. but I have no idea what you mean. *blush* Can you please elaborate?